# Secure_ssl_redirect setting for django does nothing on heroku

Tags: django, ssl, heroku, https

I am deploying a Django app on heroku and trying to force `https` on all pages. I use the following settings for that:

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

Now when I visit www.mysite.de it does in fact not redirect me to https. Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Is `SecurityMiddleware` enabled?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding the following to your settings.py:

```
PREPEND_WWW = True
BASE_URL = "https://www.mysite.de"
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.mysite.de', 'mysite.de']
```

Make sure you also have `SecurityMiddleware` and `CommonMiddleware` enabled.

Comment: It was the Missing SecurityMiddleware. Thank you.